# Can I embbed a Java EE web page inside a webview in android?

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, webview

I want to make certain reports in Java JSF using the library Primefaces for generating reports and then, showing them, just the table, inside a WebView in an android app.

Has someone did that?

Does all the funcionality of HTML5, Java EE, work fine inside a WebView in android, like they work in a browser, let's say, Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, modern WebViews are based on Google Chrome. Before you start a big project on this assumption, you could test webpages that contains similar technologies using a WebView.

I found this:

> WebView for Android
>
> Since Android 4.4 (KitKat), the WebView component is based on the
>   Chromium open source project. WebViews now include an updated version
>   of the V8 JavaScript engine and support for modern web standards
>   previously missing in old WebViews. New Webviews also share the same
>   rendering engine as Chrome for Android, so rendering should be much
>   more consistent between the WebView and Chrome.

Further down it lists some missing features: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Good advise. Thanks a lot!